# Design Patterns – Past, Present & Future Erich Gamma talk

Tags: design-patterns

There is one page 72 in Springer book "The Future of Software Engineering"
A bit confused what was a purpose to include this abstract without actual article/talk and also interested whether it exists in any format for reading ?

http://books.google.com.au/books?id=WXXlTTjMRB8C&pg=PA72&lpg=PA72&dq=Design+patterns+past+present+future+erich+gamma&source=bl&ots=-S8RfoKzDo&sig=-n55ELkfpLcHDZ-ONvbySue4NEQ&hl=en&ei=pwfqTJqbH4amvQPOnoHDCA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3&sqi=2&ved=0CCYQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=Design%20patterns%20past%20present%20future%20erich%20gamma&f=false

```
============================
Design Patterns –  Past, Present & Future 
    Erich Gamma 

IBM Rational Zurich Research Lab, Switzerland 
erich gamma@ch.ibm.com 

Abstract.    Design Patterns are now a 15 year old thought experiment. 
And  today,  for  many,  Design  Patterns  have  become  part  of  the  stan- 
dard  development  lexicon.  This  talk  looks  back  to  the  origin  of  Design 
Patterns and how they evolved since their initial description. I will then 
show patterns in action in the context of the Eclipse and Jazz platforms. 
Finally,  I  will  discuss  how  the  Design  Patterns  from  the  book  can  be 
refactored towards a Design Pattern 2.0 version. 

S. Nanz (ed.), The Future of Software Engineering, 
DOI 10.1007/978-3-642-15187-3_4, © Springer-Verlag Berlin Heidelberg 2011 
======================
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a link to the pdf and video recording
http://fose.ethz.ch/program.html

Answer (score 0):

The reference to Design Patterns in the abstract is a reference to a book.

[Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633612)

Since the book is 16 years old, you might find it at a library.

Comment: I know about this book existence. My confusion was related to "I will then show patterns in action in the context of the Eclipse and Jazz platforms.Finally,  I  will  discuss  how  the  Design  Patterns  from  the  book  can  be refactored towards a Design Pattern 2.0 version."

Comment: Eclipse is an open source integrated development environment (IDE).  Jazz is the IDE for Microsoft Visual Studio.  Gamma demonstrated his design patterns on both IDE's, and talked about the changes to the design patterns he's learned over the last 16 years.